# Config iptables ssh over VPN

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, iptables, vpn

How can I define a rule that only allows ssh via VPN in iptables?
My iptable Rule is following:

```
#!/bin/sh
IPT="/sbin/iptables"
$IPT --flush
$IPT --delete-chain
$IPT -P INPUT DROP
$IPT -P FORWARD DROP
$IPT -P OUTPUT DROP
$IPT -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW -s 0.0.0.0/0 -j DROP
$IPT -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -s 0.0.0.0/0 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -p udp --dport 1194 -m state --state NEW -s 0.0.0.0/0 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -I OUTPUT 1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
```

So only ssh and VPN connection is allowed. But i just want only a ssh connection over VPN.

Comment: Your VPN will likely come over a specific tun or tap interface, so you can add a interface specifier such as `-i tun0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just add following rules:

```
$IPT -A INPUT -i tun0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -i tun0 -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

and remove the line:

```
$IPT -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -s 0.0.0.0/0 -j ACCEPT
```

thank you @Drav Sloan for the tip.